# How to avoid the error "read ECONNRESET"?

Tags: mariadb, binlog, node.js

I'm building an API that tracks binlog files in order to notify users of some specific changes on database.

My `max_binlog_size` is set to 1048895 (1M) and after some time running the follow error is thrown on terminal:

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:205:27)
--------------------
at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:144:48)        
at Connection.query (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
at ZongJi._fetchTableInfo (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\@rodrigogs\zongji\index.js:203:23)       
at Binlog._callback (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\@rodrigogs\zongji\index.js:251:18)
at Binlog.BinlogHeader (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\@rodrigogs\zongji\lib\sequence\binlog.js:43:22)
at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:291:23)    
at Parser._parsePacket (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:433:10)        
at Parser.write (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:43:10)
at Protocol.write (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:38:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:88:28)
at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\edils\Documents\DEV\Updata\mk-auth-support-app-backend\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {


errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  fatal: true
```

I realized that everything works fine until fifth binlog file is created. That's when the sum of all existing binlog files is greater than 4 mb which theoretically exceeds `max_allowed_packet` value.

So, why does it happen? How can I overcome that problem?

My Server version: 10.0.20-MariaDB-1~jessie-log mariadb.org binary distribution

Comment: Change that setting and see what happens.  Unfortunately, you cannot set it high enough to permanently avoid the problem.  (Frankly, I don't think that setting is relevant.)

Comment: I did it and that's exactly what I realized. Make it larger won't make the problem stops.

Comment: I don't know how database replication really works but I'm starting to believe that the problem is not related to binlog files size but the cache of who is reading them. I set `max_binlog_size` to 100M (mb) and started my server when the last bin file reached 50M. For my surpise the error was thrown when the binlog file reached 54M. Based on that can you guess something about what's happening?

Comment: As each write is being replicated, it is written to the binlog.  _After_ that, if the size exceeds max_binlog_size, the file is 'rotated'.  It is also rotated when the server is restarted and when you say `FLUSH LOGS`.